# Calling another prototype method after promise completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, promise

I have following code in my node.js file;

```
GameHelperAuth.prototype.GetUserViaApi = Promise.method(function (authCookie, callback) {
// get user from API
});

GameHelperAuth.prototype.GetObjectFromCache = Promise.method(function (authCookie, callback) {
// get user from Cache
});

GameHelperAuth.prototype.GetUser = function (authCookie, callback) {    
    // check cache    
    this.GetObjectFromCache()
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                return callback(null, result);
            }
            else {
            // not found in cache, get it from API
            // **NOT WORKING HERE - undefined error**
                this.GetUserViaApi(authCookie)
                    .then(function (apiResult) {
                        return callback(null, apiResult);
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        throw err;
                    });
            }
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            throw err;
        });
```

I would like to access my instance method from another instance method once promise is completed. But it looks like it loses it's context and cannot find function anymore. (Please see where I am calling GetUserViaApi method)

Is there any way for me to reach that method without creating new instance of my class?

Comment: Don't take callback arguments - return promises. If you _must_ use callbacks, use nodeify to make a correct translation

Comment: Did you use the `var self` or the arrow function solution?

Comment: For now as easy implementation I used self. Will refactor to arrow on next release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, the simplest fix here is to just declare `var self = this` in the first line of `.GetUser()` and then use `self` instead of `this` inside the `.then` callback.

Alternatively if you're using Node 4+ with ES6 compatibility, use an "arrow function" as the outer `.then` callback that inherits the lexical `this` instead of contextual `this`:

```
return this.GetObjectFromCache()
    .then((result) => {
        if (result) {
            return callback(null, result);
        } else {
            // not found in cache, get it from API
            return this.GetUserViaApi(authCookie)
                .then(function (apiResult) {
                    return callback(null, apiResult);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    throw err;
                });
        }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        throw err;
    });
```

NB: note the addition of the `return` in the first line and in the `else` clause, necessary to ensure that the function and that branch both correctly return a promise.

FWIW, I also think you can refactor this substantially by eliminating the repeated call to `return callback(...)` through a chaining `.then`:

```
GameHelperAuth.prototype.GetUser = function (authCookie, callback) {
   return this.GetObjectFromCache()
       .then(result => result || this.GetUserViaApi(authCookie))
       .then(result => callback(null, result));
}
```

I've removed both `.catch` blocks - doing `.catch(function(err) { throw err })` is a no-op - AIUI the `throw` would make the caller end up in their own `.catch` block so you might just as well let the entire promise reject anyway.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `.catch(err => {throw err})` is a no op.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yeah, TBH I wasn't sure about the semantics of mixing `.catch` and `throw` - in my own code I would probably have let this bubble up higher without the `.catch` inside the function.  How does that chaining version look to you apart from that?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum re: your edit - I know that a single parameter arrow function doesn't require the brackets, but I prefer to put them in for consistency with the zero or 2+ parameter syntax.

Comment: The callback should also disappear. It (together with a catch()) belongs wherever `GameHelperAuth.GetUser()` is called - eg `GameHelperAuth.GetUser(authCookie).then(user => foo(null, user)).catch(...);`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I'm inclined to agree, but it depends on how often that sequence is called.  If it's multiple times then the DRY principle might suggest keeping the callback invocation where it is.

Comment: Back in the mists of time I recall taking a caning from several "experts" for daring suggest that conventional callbacks still had a place in async code. But yes, DRY can indeed be a good reason to go down that route.